# Is that correct to pass JSON in REST query?

Tags: json, rest

Is that correct to use url like that in REST-service for GET query?

```
http://localhost/service/catalog/get/{"id":1","allLayers":false}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you please select one answer friend. We will be glad ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
localhost/service/catalog/get/2/false
```

or

```
localhost/service/catalog/get/2/0
```

where `0` will be equivalent to false and `1` to true.
But seems to me you need to do something like: 
`localhost/service/catalog/get/2?allLayers=false` 
in this case.

It depends what part of your parameters is in the REST rule. In my examples I showed always the :id in the REST format and in one case I showed `allLayers` also in the rest rule that your rest service use.

Answer (score 1):

For `GET` request, your URL should look like the following:

`http://localhost/service/catalog/get?id=1&allLayers=false`

So the data will be in the query string part of the URL.

Comment: I know that, but it's a question about if it's convinient. Suggest, how would look like a query string for data like that in JSON:
{extent:{left:123,right:321,top:656,bottom:7878},params:{3:{value:5}}}

Comment: Typically, complex query data is treated as a POST of the search criteria, with the server redirecting to a GET to the result.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's highly atypical. What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to be using query parameters instead?

Comment: I'm not using query params due to that they have more long notation and less convenient for perception. Although, the way of using slash-splitted params fails cause of params possible amount. So I'm wondering if there is any other reason not to use JSON in the query string except that it is not typical

Comment: @brutallord For starters, it will break caching. Your server will treat {"id":1, "allLayers":false} and {"allLayers":false, "id":1} as the same query. No cache will do that.

Comment: May be I didn't understood you. But that query is parsed from JSON and query result is cached after that in Memcache, Redis or something like that. Or, may be, you mean browser caching?

Comment: Any cache before your server will break on those queries - browser, proxy, load balancer, or anything else between the client and your API server.